# Scrape a UEFA web page using Beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a URL. I've identified the data in the source code, but the  `.find_all()` result is `None`.

Example URL to scrape:
https://fr.uefa.com/uefaeuropaleague/season=2020/matches/round=2001148/match=2028066/statistics/index.html?iv=true

Example HTML:

```html
<div class="match-statistics--goals-scored stats-visualization--horizontal-bar match-statistics--item">
      <div class="goals-scored--values-wrap match-statistics--values-wrap">
        <div class="goals-scored--value graph-bar--number-value graph-bar--number-value__home-team" data-bind="text: homeGoalsScored">1</div>
        <div class="goals-scored--value graph-bar--number-value graph-bar--number-value__away-team" data-bind="text: awayGoalsScored">0</div>
        <div class="goals-scored--title match-statistics--sub-title">
          Buts marqués
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ko let: { width: 'width:' + (homeGoalsScored + awayGoalsScored > 0 ? (homeGoalsScored * 100 / (homeGoalsScored + awayGoalsScored)) : 0) + '%', classes: 'goals-scored-graph-bar graph-bar' + (homeGoalsScored + awayGoalsScored === 0 ? ' graph-bar__zero' : '' ) } -->
      <div class="goals-scored-graph-bar graph-bar" data-bind="attr: { class: classes }">
        <div class="goals-scored-graph-bar__value graph-bar__value" data-bind="attr: { style: width }" style="width:100%"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

My code:

```py
  req = urllib.request.Request(
      link, 
      data=None, 
      headers={
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
      }
      )
    matchs = []
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as urlpage:
        html = urlpage.read().decode()
        soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")  
        stats = soup.find_all("div",class_='match-statistics--item')
```

But `stats` is empty.

I've also tried with the full class as the selector:

```py
soup.find_all("div",class_='match-statistics--goals-scored stats-visualization--horizontal-bar match-statistics--item')
```

I just want to get all statistics, something like:

```
'Home','TOTAL DE TIRS',21
'Away','TOTAL DE TIRS',6
'Home','CADRÉS',6
'Away','CADRÉS',3
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is dynamically loaded from an API you can find in the network tab. There are different length items so I use itertools to ensure we print none where home or away item doesn't exist

```
import requests, itertools

r = requests.get('https://digital-api.uefa.com/v1/matches/2028066/statistics/team?language=FR').json()
home = {i['typeDisplayName']:i['value'] for i in r['homeTeam']['statistics']}
away = {i['typeDisplayName']:i['value'] for i in  r['awayTeam']['statistics']}

for item in itertools.zip_longest(home.keys(), away.keys(), fillvalue=None):
    if item[0]:
        print(', '.join(['Home', item[0], str(home[item[0]])]))
    if item[1]:
        print(', '.join(['Away', item[1], str(away[item[1]])]))
```

---

**Example output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot i try to find this kind of link with the api but i miss this